# How can I simplify this if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

Basically, I am doing a java program for school. The checkstyle program we are required to use is saying that I am not simplifying my if statement enough. Is there a better way to do this?

My code:

```
    if (check() == true)
    {
        return amount * 0.85;
    }
    else
    {
        return amount;
    }
```

Comment: 1. Remove `== true`. 2. Remove `else`: it is redundant after `return`.

Answer (score 4):

No need to add `== true` when you're already working with a boolean

```
if (check()) {
...
}
else {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator.

```
return check() ? amount * 0.85 : amount
```

Comment: how about, return amount * check() ? .85 : 1;

Answer (score 0):

Convert the boolean to an integer, then use that as an index int an array to get the value to multiply `amount` by, and you don't need an `if` or ternary operator:

```
return amount * (new double[] {1.0, 0.85}[Boolean.compare(check(), false)]);
```

I am kidding. This is the worst way I could come up with.

In seriousness, style checking programs mostly care about how complex your expressions are and how many potential branches there are (cyclomatic complexity), so remove the `else`, and don't compare `true` to `true` to get `true`, and that should be enough to make it happy.

Comment: You should store your double array in a private static final variable so you don't create a new one each function call! But your answer made me laugh 